# I can't edit /etc/hostfig

Tags: mysql

I want uninstall MySQL，initially I can't use `ls` and i set `vi ~/.bash_profile insert ls='ls -a'`

Then I delete `'.bash_profile.swp'` file, after this I found I can't edit `/etc/hostconfig`

> tip:-bash:edit:command not found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use the user with the correct rights and this would be root or sudo.